# How can I undo commit template?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

I once added global commit temlate by command:

```
git config --global commit.template .gitmessage.txt
```

Today I created my own repository and when I tried commit, I got error:

> fatal: could not read '.gitmessage.txt': No such file or directory

It's fine, because I don't create *.gitmessage.txt* file. I wouldn't have a template for this repo. And here comes the question: **How can I undo global commit template?** I can overwrite global commit template but I can delete thi configuration.

I was trying:

```
git config --global commit.template ""
```

but i got similar error:

> fatal: could not read '''': No such file or directory

And when I run command

```
git config --global commit.template
```

i got echo current template. Anyone can help me?

Comment: `git config --global --edit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove this section from the ~/.gitconfig file on your system.

```
[commit]
    template = .gitmessage.txt
```

Answer (score 19):

```
git config --unset --global commit.template
```